# Program compiles, but then stops working

Tags: c, debugging

So, the following program compiles, but when I go to run it, it stops working.  I do not know enough about assembly language to debug the program.  Can someone please give me some insight into what the problem might be?  If you need the Students.dat file, please let me know.  Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX 100
#define FIRSTNAME 7
#define INITIAL  1
#define LASTNAME 9
#define STREET  16
#define CITY    11
#define STATE   2
#define ZIP    5
#define START 0
#define AGE 3
#define GPA 5
#define FIRSTINDEX 8
#define IINDEX 10
#define STREETINDEX 20
#define CITYINDEX 37
#define STATEINDEX 49
#define ZIPINDEX 52
#define AGEINDEX 57
#define GPAINDEX 64

//Structures
typedef struct{
    char street[STREET + 1];
    char city[CITY + 1];
    char state[STATE + 1];
    char zip[ZIP + 1];
} Address;

typedef struct{
    char firstname[FIRSTNAME + 1];
    char intial[INITIAL + 1];
    char lastname[LASTNAME + 1];
    Address ofstudent;
    int age;
    double gpa;
} Student;

//prototypes

void strsub(char s1[], char s2[], int start, int length);
void readcontent(int *index, Student student[]);

int main(void)
{
    Student student[MAX];   // creates an empty array of student structures
    int index;
    index = 0;
    readcontent(&index, student);           // reads the file Students.dat
}

void readcontent(int *index, Student student[])         // opens content and puts it into the     array???
{
    char line[MAX];
    FILE *datafile;         //Student.dat file // its a pointer to that file and will now be        referenced to as datafile
    index = 0;

    /* try to open the data file */
    datafile = fopen("Students.dat", "r");
    if (datafile == NULL) {
        printf("'Students.dat' file not found.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read line at a time from data file */
    while (!feof(datafile)) {
        printf("Student info \n \n");
        fgets(line, MAX, datafile);
        strsub(line, student[*index].firstname, START, FIRSTNAME); // all starting indexes are given variables
        strsub(line, student[*index].intial, FIRSTINDEX, INITIAL);
        strsub(line, student[*index].lastname, IINDEX, LASTNAME);
        strsub(line, student[*index].ofstudent.street, STREETINDEX, STREET);
        strsub(line, student[*index].ofstudent.city, CITYINDEX, CITY);
        strsub(line, student[*index].ofstudent.state, STATEINDEX, STATE);
        strsub(line, student[*index].ofstudent.zip, ZIPINDEX, ZIP);
        student[*index].age = atoi(&line[AGEINDEX]);
        student[*index].gpa = atoi(&line[GPAINDEX]);
        *index++;
    }

    fclose(datafile);
}

void strsub(char s1[], char s2[], int index, int length) // strsub takes a string and puts another string into it at the end
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        s1[i] = s2[index++];
        s1[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: you do not need to know any assembly language to debug the program

Comment: (*index)++ might help.

Comment: First, specify a type for 'index' (probably an int). Second, since it is just an counter, you don't need to dereference index (i.e remove the *'s)

Comment: if you don't know assembly language, then how do you debug the program?  The program opens in Visual Studio and shows you the assembly language.

Comment: A tip: Don't use so many constants, who shall remember them all? Use `sizeof` to get the size of an array. `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` for element-count.

Comment: Did you build the program from within Visual Studio?  Normally it should show you the source code in C unless you changed some option.

Comment: Edit your question and post 3 or 4 lines of the _Students.dat_ file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change this line in `readcontent`:

```
index = 0;
```

To:

```
*index = 0;
```

Then see if the rest of your program works.

Edit: As Richard Pennington pointed out, also change:

```
*index++;
```

To:

```
(*index)++;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see anywhere in your program that prints output other than to print "Student Info".  Did you leave some part out?

Comment: Why don't you add some new code to print things out?